# How to get query based on Repository / Criteria in Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, knppaginator

How in Doctrine may I get a query based on `Criteria`?

I have the following Doctrine Criteria set:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("versionFinale", true))
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq("versionSoftDeleted", false))
    ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq("versionStatus", "PUBLISHED"));
```

Normally I would use the following code to get results:

```
$repo->matching($criteria)
```

However, as I want to use KNP Paginator I need a query.

I could use:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('a')
     ->addCriteria($criteria);
```

However this would require me to provide repo in query builder which would not be very elegant and efficient.

How may I get query based on repository & criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is not elegant in creating some sort of PaginatorQueryService? Simply implement something like this(not tested)

```
class PaginatorQueryService
{
    private $em;

    function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getPaginatorQuery($repository, $criteria)
    {
       return $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->select('entity')->from($repository, 'entity')->addCriteria($criteria)->getQuery();
    }
}
```